# AngularJS validation with ng-pattern works in desktop browser but not mobile

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, mobile

I've written a very simple regular expression to ensure that some user input is alpha numeric with a single space as follows:

```
        <input type="text" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="8" ng-pattern="/^[0-9A-Z]*\s[0-9A-Z]*$/gi" required   placeholder="Postcode" ng-model="addr.postcode"  class="form-control" name="postcode" />
        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-messages="myform.postcode.$error" ng-if="myform.$submitted || myform.postcode.$dirty">
            <div class="text-warning" ng-message="minlength">Postcode is too short.</div>
            <div class="text-warning" ng-message="pattern">Must contain a space.</div>
            <div class="text-warning" ng-message="maxlength">Postcode is too long.</div>
        </div>
```

When I test this in chrome on the desktop it works a charm.  I get a validation error if my input does not contain a space. The error clears when I enter a space.  eg "AB12 3CD" passes and "AB123CD" fails which is as I would expect.

If I open the same page on a mobile device (I've tested with iPhone 5 & 6 and a Windows Phone 8.1) the pattern always fails regardless of input. eg both "AB12 3CD" and "AB123CD" fail.

Comment: Shouldn't be any difference. But you might want to wrap your regex with `^` at its beginning and `$` at the end, just to make sure you test the entire input

Comment: I tried anchoring with ^ and  $ as suggested but makes no difference. regex works in desktop but not mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the global g option.  If I change my regular expression to

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9A-Z]*\s[0-9A-Z]*$/i"
```

it works on both mobile and desktop versions